# ddd debugger: Does exe need to be built within CygWin?

Tags: c++, windows, cygwin, ddd-debugger

On Windows I normally build my exe in a Windows command prompt with the VC Compiler and my own hand crafted makefile. I was thinking of transitioning to g++. To remove my dependency on MSVC I was thinking of installing CygWin/X and to avail of the ddd debugger. My question is: Will I then have to transition completely to the CygWin terminal or can I continue in the Windows command prompt as I am now and present my finished Windows exes to `ddd` (somehow) ?!

Answer (score 1):

ddd debugger: Does exe need to be built within CygWin? - YES. msvc compiler not compatible with gdb(cygwin) and ddd.